# Importar base MySQL con diferente estructura

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Necesito migrar registros desde una base de datos MySQL vieja a una base nueva con estructuras diferentes pero con semántica similar.

Por ejemplo:

**BaseOrigen**
Tabla DatosClientes
CodigoCliente  (PK)
Nombre
Direccion
Telefono

**BaseDestino**
Tabla Clientes
ClienteCodigo  (PK)
ClienteNombre
ClienteDireccion
ClienteTelefono
ClienteEmail

Si bien son similares, tanto el nombre de la tabla y su estructura no lo son.

Me recomiendan alguna herramienta que me ayude en este proceso.?
Gracias.

Comment: No te vamos a recomendar herramientas ni librerías en este sitio. Las preguntas del tipo: "Recomienden una librería para..." no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre opinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: PD. Si exportas como CSV, ya después puedes usar el CSV para insertar los datos incluso si no es la misma estructura, definiendo los campos adicionales a partir de otro conjunto de datos o de valores por defecto, por ejemplo

Comment: Solucion facil, importa los datos y despues hace los alter necesarios...

Comment: No estoy acá para ganar medallas sino para buscar soluciones a problemas y contribuir a soluciones para el resto. Agradezco las demás recomendaciones. Iré por el CSV. Gracias !!!!